# How to define custom server property in weblogic server 10.3

Tags: java, weblogic, environment-variables, weblogic-10.x

I need to define some properties in the weblogic enviroment to be used for an application on the startup process. I put the properties directly in the file setDomainEnv but the application doesn't get the property with this line:

```
public static final String SYSVAR_ENVIROMENT = System
        .getProperty(Constants.ENVIROMENT);
```

I'm not sure if I declared the property correctly, can anybody help me? In others application servers this type of properties could be set by the web console, but I didn't find this way in weblogic.

Answer (score 5):

In Weblogic you can achieve this in two ways:

Modify startWebLogic.sh and add your properties as -D arguments along with the others that weblogic already uses like:

```
JAVA_OPTIONS: ${SAVE_JAVE_OPTIONS} -Dmy.property=something
```

Modify your server start argument via the admin console. Login to the console and:

```
Servers link -> <server name> -> Configuration tab -> Server Start tab
```

Then you can add your -D properties to the `Arguments:` area.

If you want to verify your java properties/options are present you can either do a ps -ef and look at the server process, you can verify in the log file that the properties are present when the server starts, or you can connect to the server via `jconsole <pid>` and check the VM arguments tab.

Comment: Thanks. I put the properties in the startWebLogic as you said, but if I define it by the web console, the application doesn't see it.
I'm now weblogic adminitrator so I need to find how I can define properties without toucht any configuration file.